# Why is code section present in title Your message has been correctly sent #ct%1$s #tc%2$s in prestashop

Tags: php, e-commerce, prestashop

In prestashop email from the contact form, there is a hash code in the email title `#ct%1$s #tc%2$s`.

From what I know it contains the customer thread id and a token.

```
nous-contacter?id_customer_thread=**6**&token=**vF6a1Z8CSSzR**
```

What are the consequences if I remove it from the title in the email?

Comment: TRy to access them without !?! But I think this is URL encoded...

Answer (score 0):

If you remove it client won't be abble to click on it an go directly to frontoffice and check his answer and response.

Regards